# How to use Python module wpa_supplicant to connect to secure WiFi?

Tags: python, dbus, wpa

I'm trying to use the [*wpa_supplicant*](http://digidotcom.github.io/python-wpa-supplicant/0.2/index.html) python module to connect to wifi with wpa. In the API, I found a function called [select_network](http://digidotcom.github.io/python-wpa-supplicant/0.2/api.html#wpa_supplicant.core.Interface.select_network) which seems like it should help me to associate with a wifi AP, but I don't understand the input parameter's meaning.

The input parameter is called D-bus object path to the desired network.
After googling, I cannot find any example about using this function.

**Update**

I use d-feet to see the object paths under /fi/w1/wpasupplicant1.
Like the following:

```
/fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1
/fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/interfaces/7
/fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/interfaces/7/BSSs/14
/fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/interfaces/7/Networks/0
/fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/interfaces/7/Networks/1
```

**Update-1**

Still don't know how to deal with select_network this function.
However I found the following link:

http://www.programcreek.com/python/example/10250/dbus.Dictionary

this link describes how to use dbus module dircetly to connect to the wifi.

Any tips will be appreciate.

Answer (score 3):

Additionally to this for people struggling to get this to work you need to enable DBUS functionality on the wpa_supplicant application daemon by adding -u (enable dbus)

Quick example on how to use it, just a rough programming example.

```
from wpa_supplicant.core import WpaSupplicantDriver
from twisted.internet.selectreactor import SelectReactor
import threading
import time
import errno
import sys
import types
import netifaces
import dbus

class PythonWifiScanner:

    wifiAccessPoints = []

    def __init__(self,reactor):
        self._reactor = reactor
        threading.Thread(target=self._reactor.run, kwargs={'installSignalHandlers': 0}).start()
        time.sleep(0.2)  # let reactor start
        self.driver = WpaSupplicantDriver(reactor)
        self.supplicant = self.driver.connect()

        # get network interfaces

        self.net_iface = netifaces.interfaces()

    def get_configured_networks(self,interfaceNumber):
        return self.supplicant.get_interface(self.net_iface[interfaceNumber].decode()).get_networks()

    def get_single_wpa_interface(self,interfaceNumber):
        return self.supplicant.get_interface(self.net_iface[interfaceNumber].decode())

    def get_interfaces(self):
        return self.net_iface

    def select_network(self,network_path,interfaceNumber):
        return self.supplicant.get_interface(self.net_iface[interfaceNumber].decode()).select_network(network_path)

    def add_network(self,network_cfg,interfaceNumber):
        return self.supplicant.get_interface(self.net_iface[interfaceNumber].decode()).add_network(network_cfg)

    def scan_interface_for_networks(self,interfaceNumber):
        # Get interface and scan the network
        interface = self.supplicant.get_interface(self.net_iface[interfaceNumber].decode())
        wifiNetworks = interface.scan(block=True)
        self.wifiAccessPoints = [] 
        for singleWifi in wifiNetworks:
            self.wifiAccessPoints.append(singleWifi.get_ssid())
        return wifiNetworks

# Start a simple Twisted SelectReactor

sample_network_cfg  = {}
sample_network_cfg['psk'] = "EnterYourKeyHere"
sample_network_cfg['ssid'] = "EnterYourWifiHere"
sample_network_cfg['key_mgmt'] = "WPA-PSK"
reactor = SelectReactor()
dave=PythonWifiScanner(reactor)
value = None
bus = dbus.SystemBus()


print "Interface:" + dave.get_interfaces()[3]

# scan for available networks

for singleWifi in dave.scan_interface_for_networks(3):
    print "Wifi SSID:" + singleWifi.get_ssid()
    print "Wifi Network Type:" + singleWifi.get_network_type()

# Add network configuration to wpa_supplicant 

configpath = dave.add_network(sample_network_cfg,3)

# Attach and Select your network (will need to setip address)
dave.select_network(configpath.get_path(),3)
reactor.stop()
```